# JavaFX windows size is smaller than SceneBuilder

Tags: javafx

Ok, so I designed a scene using SceneBuilder and my problem is that when I run the code the windows is considerably smaller than it is showed in SceneBuilder.

.fxml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Hyperlink?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="480.0" prefWidth="640.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/fxml" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <left>
      <VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" spacing="40.0" style="-fx-background-color: #f2f2f2;">
         <children>
            <Label text="Log In">
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets />
               </VBox.margin>
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="15.199999809265137" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Label text="Sign Up">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="15.199999809265137" />
               </font>
            </Label>
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </left>
   <center>
      <VBox id="body" alignment="CENTER" spacing="20.0" stylesheets="@application.css">
         <children>
            <TextField layoutX="110.0" layoutY="165.0" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="260.0" promptText="username">
               <opaqueInsets>
                  <Insets />
               </opaqueInsets>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets />
               </VBox.margin>
               <padding>
                  <Insets left="15.0" />
               </padding>
            </TextField>
            <PasswordField prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="260.0" promptText="password">
               <padding>
                  <Insets left="15.0" />
               </padding>
            </PasswordField>
            <Button alignment="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="290.0" text="LOGIN" />
            <Hyperlink text="Not registered? Create an account " textFill="WHITE">
               <font>
                  <Font size="13.0" />
               </font>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets top="-10.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </Hyperlink>
         </children>
         <BorderPane.margin>
            <Insets />
         </BorderPane.margin>
         <padding>
            <Insets left="125.0" right="125.0" />
         </padding></VBox>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

The Scene is created as:

```java
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Sample.fxml"));
Scene scene = new Scene(root);
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. How do you construct the `Scene`? What are the properties of the root?

Comment: @Slaw I ve edited the post

Comment: Also the colors look a little lighter in SceneBuilder

Comment: I can't reproduce the size problem. Is that window a preview window from Scene Builder? If so, you may have resized it at one point and IIRC the preview window remembers its size. You can fix that by going to _Preview_ → _Preview Size_ → _Preferred Size_. As for the colors, I couldn't test that as you didn't provide `application.css`.

Comment: The prefered size is set to 640x480 same as in the .fxml file. The window is still considerably smaller

Comment: Don't think I'll be able to help; as I said, I can't reproduce the problem. For me, the Scene Builder content, the Scene Builder preview window, and a "real" application window all have the same size (Windows 10, JavaFX 14, Scene Builder 11.0.0)

Comment: I do not recommend Scene Builder, maybe it is a good tool, but not very "useful" in normal work. JavaFX is more pleasant when you use the TornadoFX framework and the Kotlin language.

Comment: @Slaw My JavaFX version is 8.0.211-b10, That could be the problem? How do I find the SceneBuilder version? Also I run this on Windows 7

Comment: This is probably just a case of magnification in `SceneBuilder`. In `SceneBuilder` go to `View`, select `Zoom`, and make sure `100%` is checked.

Comment: It was already set to 100%

Answer (score 1):

The issue is no longer present after I installed a newer version of JDK and a newer version of JavaFX.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the scenes size upon creation.

```
scene = new Scene(root, 640, 480);
```

Comment: The result is the same